# How to query database using dropdown value in WHERE clause

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Edited**
I have a drop down list containing a list of players, I'd like the value of a player to be displayed when they are selected from a drop down list. A bit new to JS and Ajax but have managed to cobble the below together. At the moment, nothing appears when a value is selected.

Thanks to @brombeer for the answer.

If I have ten of these can I recycle the same ajax.js and showvalue.php or do I need a one for each of the dropdowns?

**selectplayer.php**

```
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;">
            <select name="player1" id="player" onchange="showvalue()">
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY value DESC";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                 echo "<option value='". $row['playername'] ."'>" .$row['playername'] ."</option>";
                            }
                        }
                 ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="width:50%;" id="value">
        </td>
      </tr>
```

**js/ajax.js**

```
function showvalue(){
    
    var x = document.getElementById("player").value;
    
    $.ajax({
        url:"../showvalue.php",
        method: "POST",
        data:{
            id : x
        },
        success:function(data){
            $("#value").html(data)
        }
    })
}
```

**showvalue.php**

```
<?php
    ...db connection...
    $pl = $_POST['id'];
    $pl = trim($pl);
    $sql = "SELECT value FROM players WHERE playername='{$pl}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $rows['value'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: You send `id : x`, not `$_POST['value']`. That should be `$_POST['id']`