# Multiple ajax queries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have figured out how to query a database using js/ajax for a single drop-down
[How to query database using dropdown value in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880651/how-to-query-database-using-dropdown-value-in-where-clause)

I now want to add in many more identical drop-downs and have the same info called when an option is selected (I have already prevented duplicate selection)

The idea being that many choices are made which I will eventually write to a database.

Do I have to repeat the code 10 times or can I change the code to call the same query with whichever drop-down is chosen? My solution uses Id, think i may need to use classes, which i tried but couldn't get the single drop-down result with what i tried.

Code below show the single drop-down solution.

**selectplayer.php**

```
<!--player1-->
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;">
            <select name="player1" class="player">
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY value DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<option value='". $row['playername'] ."'>" .$row['playername'] ."</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="width:50%;" class="value">
        </td>
      </tr>
<!--player2-->
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;">
            <select name="player2" class="player">
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY value DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<option value='". $row['playername'] ."'>" .$row['playername'] ."</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="width:50%;" class="value">
        </td>
      </tr>
```

**js/ajax.js**

```
$("select").on("change"), function() {
    var dropdown = this;
    var id = dropdown.value;
    $.ajax({
        url:"../showvalue.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { id: id },
        success:function(data) {
            $(this).closest("td").next().html(data);
            // or remove the class if it's always the next td and
            // $(this).closest("td").next().html(data);
            // $(this).closest("tr").find("td.value").html(data);
        }
    });  
}
```

**showvalue.php**

```
<?php
    ...db connection...
    $pl = $_POST['id'];
    $pl = trim($pl);
    $sql = "SELECT value FROM players WHERE playername='{$pl}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $rows['value'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is in your "other" ("identical?") dropdowns?  Different player names?  Other fields (eg age, team)?  How should the match be made?  When all the dropdowns match? (name=ddl1 AND name=ddl2) or when any of them match (name=ddl1 *or* name=ddl2)  Or only the most recently changed value/dropdown?  Is there a different set of results for each drop down?

Comment: I have 10 drop downs all with the same options. I have prevented duplicate selections with another script. When I select an option I want the value to appear. I can do this for one drop-down but struggling to do it with all of them.

Comment: Ah - you're selecting a "team" of 10 players?   Use `this` and DOM navigation to set the "value" column

Comment: @freedomn-m I have edited my code above with your answer below but i'm not getting any values nor any errors in the console, any ideas?

Comment: You have a typo -> `$("select").on("change", function() {`  you have `.on("change"), function`  https://jsfiddle.net/f7ady8ke/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a extra parameter link a flag or field name by which you change add multiple query by using flag like this

```
 <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;">
            <select name="player1" id="player" onchange="showvalue('player1')">
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY value DESC";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                 echo "<option value='". $row['playername'] ."'>" .$row['playername'] ."</option>";
                            }
                        }
                 ?>
            </select>
        </td>


        <td style="width:50%;">
            <select name="player1" id="player" onchange="showvalue('player2')">
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY value DESC";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                 echo "<option value='". $row['playername'] ."'>" .$row['playername'] ."</option>";
                            }
                        }
                 ?>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td style="width:50%;" id="value">
        </td>
      </tr>


    function showvalue(flag){
    
    var x = document.getElementById("player").value;
    
    $.ajax({
        url:"../showvalue.php",
        method: "POST",
        data:{
            id : x,
            flag:flag
        },
        success:function(data){
            $("#value").html(data)
        }
    })
}




      <?php
        ...db connection...
        $pl = $_POST['id'];
        $flag = $_POST['flag'];
        $pl = trim($pl);
if($flag=="player1"){
        $sql = "SELECT value FROM players WHERE playername='{$pl}'";
}else
{
    $sql = "SELECT value FROM players WHERE playername2='{$pl}'";
}
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo $rows['value'];
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: playername2 is not a column in the table players

Answer (score 0):

As you've identified, you can't use the same ID each time.

Within your ajax success, you can use DOM navigation to find the relevant output cell.

If you change your `onchange=` to an event

```
$("#player_table").find("select").on("change", function() { showvalue(this) });
```

and change your `value` td to a class:

```
<td style="width:50%;" class="value"></td>
```

you can use `this` (you can also pass `this` in the onchange=)

```
function showvalue(element) {
    var dropdown = this;
    var id = dropdown.value;
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: { id: id },
        success:function(data) {
            $(this).closest("tr").find("td.value").html(data);
            // or remove the class if it's always the next td and
            // $(this).closest("td").next().html(data);
        }
    });  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, where does the onchange= event go? Is this in the <select>?

Comment: You *either* remove onchange from `<select onchange=`  and use a proper event (`$("select").on("change"...` goes directly above `function showvalue`)) *or* you change `onchange="showvalue()"` to `onchange="showvalue(this)"` - either way you need to pass in the element to the event.  WIth a jquery event you could also use `event.target`